# Can shellshock redirect my visits on nginx?

Tags: bash, shellshock-bash-bug

I have a problem with my nginx webserver

Once a day some clients get redirected to random webpages (bad ones), I've checked for malware, virus and nothing comes up.

But I recently read about CDorked infection and I installed tools to detect it and even did it by hand... but nothing came up.

So I Scanned the server for shellshock and it was vulnerable..

my question is.. Can shellshock be redirecting my clients to other websites? or maybe the attacker infected some binaries through there?

Thanks

Comment: The Shellshock vulnerability allows arbitrary code execution, so yes, it's possible, but there are no details in your question that would allow us to confirm or deny that it is involved in anway.

Comment: @chepner Yea I know, its a bit hard for me too to dig on the issue.. any recommendation? I've tried malware detection and tried to check for Cdorked symptoms (like shearch for shared memory programs), but nothing  comes up

Comment: Fix the shellshock vulnerability. If the problem persists, it wasn't because of it.

Comment: @Barmar I already did that.. then I'll have to wait

Comment: be sure to update your question with results of your test. Good luck.